# Where are excel files created using XLConnect saved?

Tags: r

R is very new to me. I have a simple question. I created an excel file using XLConnect and saved it.

```
library(XLConnect)
data <- loadWorkbook("mydata.xls",create=TRUE)
saveWorkbook(data)
```

But I do not know exactly where it is saved. I did a search on my computer and could not find it. Any suggestions please?

Comment: It would be easier to answer if you edited your question to include the exact code you used to create the Excel file.

Answer (score 4):

They are saved in your current working directory. In order to find out which is your working directory use `getwd()`

You can also change the current directory by using `setwd("desired directory")`

Comment: @xuan you're welcome! Glad to be useful. Consider accepting this answer as correct by doing clic in the green tick mark if this meets your needs.